# AzerothCore: does rate.drop.item.quality from the worldserver.conf affect world drops?

Tags: azerothcore

I want to modify world drop rates, but I'm not sure how the rate.drop.item works. It seems to not affect all drops as I would have expected.

I've done some testing using various values from 200 all the way up to 10,000,000 and the results seem strange. Normal enemies don't seem to drop world blues any higher than normal, unless it's something normally on their drop table, like a blueprint or something (I tested this on many enemies across a few different zones). Enemies in dungeons drop many more BoE blues, but it would appear to be BoE drops specific to the instance, not world drops.

Oddly, chests seem to act as I would expect, if I have the rate.drop.item.rare set to a very high value, I will receive several world drop rares from the chest. It just doesn't seem to affect creatures.

I don't think this matters, but I was testing this with GM privileges.

Can anyone clarify more precisely how this configuration option works, and if it doesn't affect world drops, is there a config that does, or will I have to edit some tables to achieve this?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I ended up modifying the database directly. Here's the update I ran

```
UPDATE acore_world.creature_loot_template INNER JOIN reference_loot_template ON creature_loot_template.reference = reference_loot_template.entry
INNER JOIN item_template ON reference_loot_template.item = item_template.entry
SET creature_loot_template.Chance = creature_loot_template.Chance*5
WHERE creature_loot_template.Reference != 0 AND creature_loot_template.Chance < 1 AND (item_template.quality = 3 OR item_template.quality = 4)
AND creature_loot_template.GroupId != 0 AND (reference_loot_template.comment NOT LIKE '%ReferenceTable%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Loots are managed in AzerothCore is more complex than it seems: it is not only about the drop chance of every single item but there are also other factors for example Groups etc...

I recommend reading:

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/loot_template

To understand how the core reads the loot tables.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did run through all that and made some changes to the world database directly. My guess is the worldserver.config option does not seem to affect all loot_templates, or at least for the creature one it doesn't seem to affect the ones referencing world drops.